# Will transforms in css cause blurring due to evaluating to half pixels?

Tags: css, css-transforms, blurry, subpixel

Lets say you use this code to vertically center an element

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

(this question isn't about aligning things though, so please no suggestions about alignment)

Could this cause your element to become blurry?

[This article](http://martinkool.com/post/27618832225/beware-of-half-pixels-in-css) mentions that using translate can position elements at half-pixel values, thus causing blur on some browsers. Do browsers still do this, or have they been patched to not blur?  If you use a percentage as the argument to translate, could the percentage evaluate to a non-integer pixel value (thus allowing the possibility of blur), or does it get rounded? EX: if you use 66%, could this lead to a fractional pixel value?  [This article](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/) claims that you can set `transform-style: preserve-3d;` on the element's parent to avoid blurring, but someone in the comments claimed that it didn't work for him.. does it actually work?

Comment: Browsers are only part of the equation here. When doing a transform devices will typically hardware accelerate (cache) the element. In my experience that has been the greatest cause of this blurring issue. I've even run into a certain device that would actually down sample when hardware accelerating.

Answer (score 1):

Yes browsers do still do this. Having this issue on Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100

And `transform-style: preserve-3d;` doesn't resolve this issue either.

Instead use flexbox with to centre the item.

```
.child-not-blurred {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution (not the best one) is to set Blur: 0. But there are some edge cases.

Comment: In Chrome, this is: -webkit-filter: blur(0px);